# Quotient Topology and Identifying Points

Tags: general-topology

I am working on some examples where we identify points and figure out what the quotient topology looks like. Below is the four examples with my guesses. Am I right? What do I need to change?

The disk with its boundary points identified with each other to form a single point: 
My Guess: Honestly no clue here

The interval [0, 4] in R with integer points identified with each other to form a single point:
My Guess: {0,1,2,3,4},(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)

The sphere with the equator collapsed to a point.:
My Guess: Looks like an hour glass with two hemispheres

The real line R with [−3, −1] ∪ [1, 3] collapsed to a point:
My Guess: NO clue. Sorry guys.

The real line R with (−1, 1) collapsed to a point.:
My Guess: (-1,1) U Any other open set in R

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, when you image forming a quotient space, you are gluing the identified points together, and you can be flexible (up to homeomorphism) with how the rest of the space behaves. Topology doesn't care about bending or stretching. [This](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Disk_to_Sphere_using_Quotient_Space.gif) answer to your first question may help you get a feel for it.

2: Get a rope and glue the five points (including the endpoints) together; you get four circles all joined at one point, more precisely the wedge sum of four circles.

3: Get an infinitely long rope, pinch each interval into a single point (effectively changing nothing), then glue the two points together; you have a line attached to a circle.

4: In this case the result would be a slightly harder-to-imagine non-Hausdorff space consisting of the collapsed point $a$ and the two pieces $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$. The inverse image of $a$ is $(-1,1)$ so $a$ is itself open, but any open set containing 1 (or -1) in the quotient space has to contain $a$ as well, so it is non-Hausdorff. Other open sets (consisting a basis) would look like $(x,a]$, $[a,y)$, and of course $(x,y)$.